# After closing form, go back to main form and transfer parameters

Tags: delphi

I have this code here I use to open form in Delphi

```
procedure TEventForm.OpenEv;
var
  Form: TOpenEvForm;
begin
      Form.CreateForm;
      Form.ShowModal;
      Form.Release
  end
end;
```

When I open the `TOpenEvForm` form, it contains a bit of text, a datepicker and an 'Ok' button. What I need to do is when clicked the Ok button to call the `EventAdd` procedure in the first form and to pass the datepicker as a variable.

I could call the `EventAdd` procedure from the second form, but it's not clean.
Or is there any way to close the form `TOpenEvForm` but run the `EventAdd` procedure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
procedure TEventForm.OpenEv;
var
  Form: TOpenEvForm;
begin
  Form := TOpenEvForm.Create(nil);
  try
    if Form.ShowModal = mrOk then
      EventAdd(Form.DateTimePicker1.DateTime);
  finally
    Form.Free;
  end;
end;
```